# how to use multiple when conditions in pyspark for updating column values

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I am looking for a solution where we can use multiple when conditions for updating a column values in pyspark.

I am currently trying to achieve a solution when we have multiple conditions in spark how we can update a column. I have one dataframe in which we have three columns DATE, Flag_values, salary:

```
df = df.withColumn('Flag_values', F.when(F.col('DATE') < '2019-08-01', 'GIVEHIKE').otherwise(''))
```

After this I have to update the same column Flag_values now with multiple conditins:

```
new_column=when((col("Flag_values")=='') & (col("DATE")<'2019-12-15'),'GIVE BONUS ONLY').otherwise('')
df = df.withColumn("Flag_values", new_column)
```

But when I am running these two queries together the second query is overwriting the first query with data which I dont want. I want data for both query conditions.

The other queries that I have also tried are:

```
df = df.withColumn('Flag_values', F.when(F.col('DATE') < '2019-08-01', 'GIVEHIKE').otherwise('PYTHON'))

df = df.withColumn('Flag_values', F.when((F.col('DATE') < '2019-12-15') & (F.col('Flag_values') == 'PYTHON') , 'GIVE BONUS').otherwise('JAVA'))
```

I thought may be otherwise null is creating issue, but again after running the query I am getting output of second query only. Seems like it is overwriting first query data. Is there any approach by which we can achieve this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **second query is overwriting the first query**

To avoid that you can pass data frame column value in `.otherwise` So it will replace the value you want and keep the previous value as it is.

- **My sample Dataframe**

[image]

- **Query I used**

```py
df2 = df1.withColumn('Flag_values', when(df1.date < '2019-08-01', 'GIVEHIKE').otherwise(''))
new_column=when((df2.Flag_values == '') & (df2.date < '2019-12-15'),'GIVE BONUS ONLY').otherwise(df2.Flag_values)
df3 = df2.withColumn("Flag_values", new_column)
df3.show()
```

- **Execution**
  [image]